# How to achieve copy of a cell on drag and drop in DHTMLX grids?

Tags: html, grid-layout, dhtmlx

After Googling, I found that [dthmlx copy](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/05_drag_n_drop/02_pro_drag_events.html), one can enable copy in order to copy the rows on drag and drop. But I am looking for the same at the granularity of cells. On selecting and drag-n-drop of a cell, I want to copy its value to neighboring cells.

Is there a any way to do that in dhtmlx grids ?

Comment: You can attach event 'onDrop' on the grid that will give you rowId and then you can read particular cell value based on index of cell to use.

Comment: In that case, How can we get all the selected rows ?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you want to copy cell contents but you can loop thorugh number of dragged rows using: yourgrid._dragged.length and then extract the data within loop with something like: yourgrid.cellById(yourgrid._dragged[i].idd,0).getValue().
For more you can check dhtmlx drag-n-drop [advanced features](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__drag_and_drop.html).